# Splash screen crashes (Logcat errors)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am developing an android application when I run my application it crashes
every time. There are logcat errors which I have posted here. I don't know what to do.
Here is my code of splash screen:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                sleep(2000);  //Delay of 3 seconds
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MaainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Second page:

```
EditText etPhoneNumber;
EditText RandomNumber;
Button Submit;
Button response;
protected String PhoneNumber;
protected String EnteredNumber;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etPhoneNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    RandomNumber =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    response = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);  
     response.setOnClickListener(this);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        InputStream is=null;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             PhoneNumber=""+etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();


            Log.i("Tag","Phone number: "+PhoneNumber);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber));
            try{
                HttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.4/older/index.php");                   
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.i("Tag","UR;"+ response);
                HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
                Log.i("Tag","UR;"+ entity);
                is = entity.getContent();
                String msg="Data is entered successfully" +PhoneNumber;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                Log.e("ClientProtocol","Log_tag");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Excep: "+e);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("Log_tag","IOException"); 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

//New Thread
    Thread thread =new Thread (new Runnable() 
    { 
        @Override public void run() 

    {


     OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
          InputStream is=null;

             public void onClick(View v) {

                 String result = "";
                 EnteredNumber=""+RandomNumber.getText().toString();
                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EnteredNumber", EnteredNumber));
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered"+ EnteredNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 try
                      {
                        HttpClient httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.4/older/check.php");
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                        }
                   catch(ClientProtocolException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("ClientProtocol","Log_tag");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Excep: "+e);    
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Log_tag","IOException"); 
                        e.printStackTrace();    
                    }try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        reader.close();
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                    Log.i("log_tag","result: "+ result); 

                        JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);
                        String returnString = "";
                        returnString = jArray.getString("RandomNumber");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json is :" + returnString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("log_tag","value:"+jArray.getString("RandomNumber"));
                        if (!jArray.isNull("returnString")) {
                            JSONObject Object = jArray.getJSONObject("returnString");
                        }
                       boolean retVal;
                        retVal = returnString.equals("0");
                        if(retVal) 
                        { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User verified ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MaainActivity.this, ContactList.class);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        }
                        else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not verified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        }

                catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

             } }; 

      response.setOnClickListener(stopListener); 

}
    });

      thread.start();   
}     




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Logcat errors:

```
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): Process: com.example.verificationdatabase, PID: 1395
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.themifyContext(AppCompatViewInflater.java:168)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:79)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:912)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:966)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3022)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3085)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1678)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:148)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.example.verificationdatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-13 07:02:49.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 07:19:56.444: I/Process(1395): Sending signal. PID: 1395 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Right at the very top it's telling you there is something wrong with the class definition.

Comment: now logcat is showing this
09-13 08:17:20.704: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 08:17:20.704: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): Process: com.example.verificationdatabase, PID: 1818
09-13 08:17:20.704: E/AndroidRuntime(1818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.verificationdatabase/com.example.verificationdatabase.MaainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 08:17:20.704: E/AndroidRuntime(1818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)

Answer (score 1):

can you check whether you have added this activity in your manifest file. I think it is missing.

Comment: Now my Console is showing this error
I never saw that error before :(

[2015-09-13 06:06:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;
[2015-09-13 06:06:34 - VerificationDatabase] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;
[2015-09-13 06:41:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;;

Comment: Now there is a nullpointerexception in my logcat.
09-15 02:59:27.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main09-15 02:59:27.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): Process:com.example.verificationdatabase, PID: 1004
09-15 02:59:27.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.verificationdatabase/com.example.verificationdatabase.MaainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 02:59:27.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1004):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)09-15 02:59:27.040: E/AndroidRuntime(1004)

Comment: Can you paste your  activity in manifest  file. Here I guess there is some spelling mistake i manifest.